# How to find first data row and column of excel in python xlwings

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, row, xlwings

I want to find first data row and column of excel in python xlwings. Below are examples:

[image]

Or

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the safest to do this would be to use `API` property and simply use `VBA` [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method. We can now search for anything using a `*` wildcard to make sure you find formulas (that could show `""`) AND values. A simplified example:

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False)
wb = app.books.add()
ws = wb.sheets.active
ws['C2'].value = 'check'
row_cell = ws.api.Cells.Find(What="*", After=ws.api.Cells(ws.api.Rows.Count, ws.api.Columns.Count), LookAt=xw.constants.LookAt.xlPart, LookIn=xw.constants.FindLookIn.xlFormulas, SearchOrder=xw.constants.SearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection=xw.constants.SearchDirection.xlNext, MatchCase=False) 
column_cell = ws.api.Cells.Find(What="*", After=ws.api.Cells(ws.api.Rows.Count, ws.api.Columns.Count), LookAt=xw.constants.LookAt.xlPart, LookIn=xw.constants.FindLookIn.xlFormulas, SearchOrder=xw.constants.SearchOrder.xlByColumns, SearchDirection=xw.constants.SearchDirection.xlNext, MatchCase=False)
print((row_cell.Row, column_cell.Column))
```

We can use `SearchDirection.xlNext` and start in the very last `Excel` cell. This is a [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/9758194) way in `VBA` to reliably find your last used row/column, but can also reliably find your first row/column.